# While running Ansible playbook getting error install request library

Tags: ubuntu, ansible, python-requests

I am trying to create a vm on gcp using ansible playbook on my ansible master machine
my ansible master is on ubuntu-desktop(WSL)
I have installed requests and google-auth
but while running playbook, I am getting error

"FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {"discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"}, "changed": false, "msg": "Please install the requests library"}"

and while running "pip3 install requests". It is prompting it's already present
"Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (2.22.0)"

Comment: It is not clear on which machine you are running the install. The library is expected to exist on your target server.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem, I was getting "please install the requests library" because I was not installing requests on host server,
requests module needs to be installed on slave machine as well.

Answer (score 0):

You just will need to make sure you have [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) library in your local host

Just install requests

```
pip install requests
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a `requirements.yaml` playbook file with package to install :

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    pip_package_requirements:
      - "requests"
      - "google-auth"
      - "google-auth-httplib2"
      - "google-auth-oauthlib"
      - "google-cloud"
      -
  tasks:
    - name: Install pip requests library
      pip:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        state: present
      with_items: "{{ pip_package_requirements }}"
```

And I import this playbook

```
- import_playbook: requirements.yaml
```